# TextInput field retrieving undefined and not showing the value on the list screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to add some new items on a list but when i print the list on console log it adds the item but  it shows me undefined of name and description. Apparantly there is something wrong with the inputs but I cannot figure out why.
Also on the app itself the it shows that a new item is added but without data.

```
import React ,{useState}from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity,Keyboard,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Task from './components/task';


export default function App(){


  
      const [recipeName,setRecipeName]=useState("");
      const [descriptionItem, setDescriptionItem] = useState("");
      const [items, setItems] = useState([
        { itemName: "Chicken", description: "chicken test", id: 0 }
      ]);
    
  

  

  const handleAddButtonClick = () => {
    
    const newItem = {
      itemName: recipeName, // change
      descriptionItem: descriptionItem,
      id: items.length
    };
    console.log(newItem);
    const newItems = [...items, newItem];

    setItems((state) => {
      console.log(state);
      console.log(newItems);
      return newItems;
    });
    // setRecipeName("");
    // setDescriptionItem("");
    // console.log(items.description);
    // console.log(items.id); //...
  };


 

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {/* Added this scroll view to enable scrolling when list gets longer than the page */}
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flexGrow: 1
      }}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    >

    {/* Today's Tasks */}
    <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Today's tasks</Text>
      <View style={styles.items}>
        {/* This is where the tasks will go! */}
        {
          items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity key={index}  onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
                <Text>Recipe {item.itemName}  Description: {item.description}</Text>
                
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    </View>
      
    </ScrollView>

    {/* Write a task */}
    {/* Uses a keyboard avoiding view which ensures the keyboard does not cover the items on screen */}
    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
    >

<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Write a name'} value={recipeName} onChangeText={(text) => setRecipeName(text)} />
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Write a date'} value={descriptionItem} onChange={(text) => setDescriptionItem(text)} />

  </View>


    
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddButtonClick()}>
        <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    
  </View>
  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E8EAED',
  },
  tasksWrapper: {
    paddingTop: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  items: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  writeTaskWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 60,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 250,
  },
  addWrapper: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    borderRadius: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  addText: {},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over items in your `map()` function here:

```
items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={index}
                  onPress={() => completeTask(index)}
                >
                  <Text>
                    Recipe {item.itemName} Description: {item.description}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })
```

You are not using the correct state value. Instead of `item.description`, it should be `item.descriptionItem`.

I also advise you to move `onChange` events to separate methods and set the state inside them, do not use anonymous functions. So, for example, for your description, it would be something like this:

```
const handleDescription = (e) => { 
    setDescriptionItem(e.target.value);
};
```

And in your JSX:

```
<TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder={"Write a date"}
        value={descriptionItem}
        onChange={handleDescription}
/>
```

UPDATE:

I recreated your code in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-ganguly-pb7pwk?file=/src/App.js), with minor changes:

- commented out the import of `Task` component (since I don't know what that component does)
- disabled `onPress` event handler as I don't have access to `completeTask` function
- changed the `onChangeText` for `recipeName` to `onChange`
- extracted both `onChange` events to separated methods.
- fixed initial state for `items`; it also had `description` , instead of `descriptionItem`

Please, feel free to check it out.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe it'll help

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works on your sandbox and not on my own app ? Still the same issue as i mentioned

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your code alongside with the console, to see exactly what error is being thrown?

Comment: Fixed the problem.